Why does rtsp over udp need to provide the client_port during setup instead of just using the source port of the received packet?
After all, it's difficult for a client behind NAT to get a right port that can be reached.
In contrast, the server's UDP ports are all reachesable.
If the server uses the source address and source port from the UDP messages it receives, combined with SSRC or other session IDs, it is easy to correlate to the corresponding UDP bearer.
Why isn't the protocol designed this way?

Just imageing Server Port is not useable on client side because its already taken for example. the client ack the Client port or set an diffrent one to ensure a reachable port
